# Possible to use customErrors=On, but only for non-IIS handled errors?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, web-config

I toggled customErrors=On in web.config, set the defaultRedirect for my custom Error.aspx page. However, this is only to prevent application errors from spitting out code - I'd still like IIS to handle 404s etc. with its default handlers, since they work fine.

Any way to specify in my ASP.NET app or IIS for IIS to take priority?

I know I could add the formatting in my Error page...but I'd just be replicating what exists in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't tried it (I don't have visual studio on that box) but maybe if you set your customErrors to handle only error 500 (server error), that'll work. Just a guess.

Let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the web.config file

```
<customErrors = "On">
   <error statusCode = "404" redirect = "route_name"/>
</customErrors>
```

Don't forget to register the route in the Global.asax.cs